# UIView Flip Animation Issue

Tags: ios, xcode, animation, uiview, flip

I've adopted a fairly well used method of flipping between two images. However on this occasion, for reasons currently beyond me - the animation is currently only flipping from "newView" to "newView."

Any help pointing towards the error of my ways would be greatly appreciated. Code as follows:

```
UIImageView *oldView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"dark_wood.png"]];
UIImageView *newView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"light_wood.png"]];
[container addSubview:oldView];
```

and:

```
[UIView transitionWithView:container
                  duration:2
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
                animations:^{ [oldView removeFromSuperview]; [container addSubview:newView]; }
                completion:nil];
```

(It's probably something v.simple beyond this code..)

Comment: Is all of this code all in one method? If not, show the complete methods so we can see how your code is structured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*The solution:*

The method I was using to initiate the flip was at fault. I had a UISlider call for the flip - but without a system in place to stop it from doing so, it was continuously calling the flip animation - with the consequences as described!

Solution in code as follows:

Create a `BOOL` to stop the `UISlider` repeatedly calling the animation:

```
BOOL playing;
```

IBAction for the UISlider:

```
- (IBAction)slider:(id)sender {
    if (!playing) {
        [UIView transitionWithView:self.view
                      duration:3
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
                    animations:^{ [view1 removeFromSuperview]; [self.view addSubview:view2]; }
                    completion:nil];
        playing = YES;
    }
}
```

Thanks to Tony for helping with this. A lesson if ever there was one to keep the script clean!

Answer (score 1):

it could possibly be that they are UIImageViews however here is some example code of it working for me. Here is a view controller with the view did load method looking like so

```
[super viewDidLoad];
view1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
view1.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50);
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(thusFar:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[view1 addSubview:button];
[self.view addSubview:view1];
```

And here is the method that is called by the button

```
-(void)thusFar:(id)sender
{

    UIView *view2 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
    view2.backgroundColor = [UIColor brownColor];
    [UIView transitionWithView:self.view duration:5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft animations:^{ [view1 removeFromSuperview]; [self.view addSubview:view2]; } completion:nil];
}
```

This works for me. Go ahead and use this code as an example. But the only different I see is that you are using UIImageViews instead of UIViews. Now I know that UIImageView is a child of UIView but that might be a problem.

Comment: Thanks for your response Tony, I did try using UIViews but unfortunately - the same result..

Comment: Maybe try explicitly specify the frames? I know that in order to do animation they would need handling to those, possibly because they are not explicitly somewhere something isnt getting initialized.

Comment: I think you could well be right, there's all sorts of translations, rotations and image changes going on in this script! I shall have a trawl through

Comment: Tony, thanks for your help - your example helped me to realise that the method I was using to initiate the flip was at fault (I'm sure had I disclosed this, you'd have pointed this out!). I had a UISlider call for the flip - but without a system in place to stop it from doing so, it was continuously calling the flip animation - with the consequences as described! 
I really should clean this code up...

Comment: Ahhhh got yah. That makes sense. Well glad u got that figured out!